# Trying to parse html hidden by javascript

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsoup

I've created a simple java script that used Jsoup to parse a page of data. The site creators have changed the page however, so much that if there is a certain amount of data on the page it gives you the opinion to refine your search, or, you can click a link and the data will come up. I've been tearing my hair out trying to find a solution, the url doesn't change, and the href for the link is just `javacript:void(0);`. Is there any way I can get at the html containing the data just using my script?

Comment: You will need to execute the Javascript.

Comment: Can I do that within my code using jsoup? Sorry, I don't have any experience dealing with this, I'm not rly sure what to google =/

Comment: Jsoup does not execute Javascript. You might have to switch libraries.

Comment: This is not a solution, but a workaround, you could surf with the browser to the page examine the page and figure out what the javascript does, maybe you can get around it, wihtout having to execute javascript. If not you would have to switch the lib as **Terry Li** mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use something that drives a web browser like [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/). That's the only one I have used, never needed anything else. I'm sure there are different ones that may suit you better, you should test a few, or not.. Once you get the javascript elements with selenium (or whatever web driver you choose) parse them into JSoup Elements. 
This way you wouldn't have to completely change libs, but just add one.

Also, there are ways you can work around javascript by watching what changes in browser's address bar.

Answer (score 1):

Use firefox's or chrome's developer tools. When you click on the link, there is propably an ajax call firing. On the network tab, you can see which url the javascript actually requests and how the result is structured (propably json). Then you can directly access that url to load the rest of the results.

Or something along those lines ^^