# I am using to jsoup to pull images from website url, but I want the page to load first is there anyway to do this?

Tags: java, javascript, image, jsoup

The problem is that some of the urls I am trying to pull from have javascript slideshow containers that haven't loaded yet. I want to get the images in the slideshow but since this hasn't loaded yet it doesn't grab the element. Is there anyway to do this? This is what I have so far

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2013/03/pictures/130316-gastric-brooding-frog-animals-weird-science-extinction-tedx/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+ng%2FNews%2FNews_Main+%28National+Geographic+News+-+Main%29").get();
Elements jpg = doc.select("img[src$=.jpg]");
```

Answer (score 1):

jsoup can't handle javascript, but you can use an additional library for this:

- [Parse JavaScript with jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904776/parse-javascript-with-jsoup/14925848#14925848)
- [Trying to parse html hidden by javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13666453/trying-to-parse-html-hidden-by-javascript/14715242#14715242)