# Jsoup How can i parse element which show after click button (image)?

Tags: html, parsing, onclick, jsoup

I have this div in source of website, and after click it shows more data.

```
            <div class=infogroup>
                <div onClick=requestAjax(); style=cursor:pointer; class=infoheading>Your Panels (Click to load results)<img style=float:right; src="/images/plus_sign.png" width=20 height=20></div>
                <div id=resultsPanels style=display:none;>
                    <table width=100%>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <center>Loading your results...</center>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <center><img src=/images/ajaxloader.gif></center>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
```

when i click it and do "inspect element" witch chrom i can see it in source website
when i copy xpatch the xpatch of interesting field is:

```
//*[@id="resultsPanels"]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]
```

how do i select it in Jsoup ?

i tried like this but it isnt working:

```
elements = doc.select("//*[@id=\"resultsPanels\"]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]");
```

this is what mozzila do when i click button:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup **doesn't support** *javascript / ajax*, but you can use an external library for that (i've listed some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13666453/trying-to-parse-html-hidden-by-javascript/14715242#14715242)).

Btw. is using *CSS / jQuery* selector syntax, not *XPath*. So this syntax will likely fail.

You can get an overview about Jsoups selector here: [Use selector-syntax to find elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13666453/trying-to-parse-html-hidden-by-javascript/14715242#14715242)

Comment: for example: `//*[@id="resultsPanels"] .div .table .tbody .tr[3] .td[3]` ?

Comment: selector isnt gona help here i have to parse this ajaxscript result
and in your examples i cant find it