# Get tabledata from html, JSOUP

Tags: html, web-scraping, jsoup

What is the best way to extract data from a table from an url?

In short I need to get the actual data from the these 2  tables at: http://www.oddsportal.com/sure-bets/

In this example the data would be "Paddy power" and "3.50"
See this image:

(Sorry for posting image like this, but I still need reputation, i will edit later)
http://img837.imageshack.us/img837/3219/odds2.png

I have tried with Jsoup, but i dont know if this is the best way?
And I can't seem to navigate correctly down the tables, I have tried things like this:

```
    tables = doc.getElementsByAttributeValueStarting("class", "center"); 
    link = doc.select("div#col-content > title").first();
    String text1 = doc.select("div.odd").text();
```

The tables thing seem to get some data, but doesn't include the text in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, man. The second field you want to retrieve is filled by JavaScript. Jsoup does not execute JavaScript.
To select title of first row you can use:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.oddsportal.com/sure-bets/").get();
     Elements tables = doc.select("table.table-main").select("tr:eq(2)").select("td:eq(2)");
     System.out.println(tables.select("a").attr("title"));
```

Chain selects used for visualization.

Comment: Oh, thats a shame..
Is there a way to get the data filled by JavaScript some way then?

Comment: Unfortunately not with Jsoup, but please see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13666453/trying-to-parse-html-hidden-by-javascript/14715242#14715242 I've listed some libraries which may help you.

Comment: Im still pretty new to programming :(
Which of these other libraries would handle my problem best/easiest?
I cant really find any good examples with any of those

Comment: @Yoshidk HtmlUnit is best for you I think. You can find examples on their site http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html