# Not expecting output with page parsing

Tags: java, database, parsing, jsoup

i'm trying to parsing the results of a website of soccer statistics, and build a database.

I'm using jsoup library, and i've this code that another user yesterday wrote for me.

The page i'm trying to parse is this:
[goalnow](http://info.nowgoal.com/en/League.aspx?SclassID=34&MatchSeason=2007-2008)

and i'm using this code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.*;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class HTMLParser {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
 String url = "http://info.nowgoal.com/en/League.aspx?SclassID=34&MatchSeason=2007-2008";
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

Elements stats = document.select("#Table3 tbody tr ");

for(int i = 0; i < stats.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(stats.get(i).text());
}

  }
}
```

i'm looking for the all table in output, but i 've this:

> No. Date Home Score Away Handicap Over/Under Data
>   FT HT FT HT

basically, the first row. What is wrong with my code? Can someone help me to understand how to parse this kind of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is ok, the problem is: The website uses *JavaScript* for it's content. Unfortunately JSoup doesn't support JS.

The first row is parsed because it's common Html. Btw. it's always helpful to check how Jsoup sees a website:

```
String url = "http://info.nowgoal.com/en/League.aspx?SclassID=34&MatchSeason=2007-2008";
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

System.out.println(document);
```

But you can have a look at my answer here: [Trying to parse html hidden by javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13666453/trying-to-parse-html-hidden-by-javascript/14715242#14715242)

There I have listed some JavaScript libraries which can help you.