# scraping using Jsoup

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, jsoup

I am scraping a E-Commerce website using Jsoup. in this i want to get tags like , and price.
after Jsoup.parse(), i am unable to getting this .

```
<div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl03_Showcase">
 <div class="controlcontent_r">
  <div class="bucketgroup">
   <div class="prod_viewsparent">
    <div class="bucket" style="width: 175px; height: 280px;">
     <div class="bucket_left">
      <a href="/Products/Buy-Online-Electronics-Cameras-Digital-Cameras/Nikon/Nikon-Coolpix-L27-Point--Shoot/pid-2849731.aspx">
       <img class="mtb-img" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" src="http://resources-images.martjackhosting.com/s3/martjack-resources/5d4b3aa1-119a-4d82-b9bb-1b6bdbd62002/Images/ProductImages/Source/NikonL27-BLK.jpg;width=150;height=150;scale=canvas" alt="Nikon Coolpix L27 Point & Shoot" title="Digital Cameras, Nikon, Nikon Coolpix L27 Point & Shoot"></a>
      <div id="2849731" class="btn_quick_view" style="display:none">
      <a rel="2849731,0,2466375,5d4b3aa1-119a-4d82-b9bb-1b6bdbd62002" href="#">Quick View</a></div>
   <h4 class="mtb-title">Nikon Coolpix L27 Point & Shoot</h4>
    <div class="mtb-desc">
      <span class="mtb-price">
        <label class="mtb-mrp">
        <b class="lb1"> MRP </b>
        <span class="WebRupee">Rs. </span>
          4,990
       </label>
        <label class="mtb-ofr">
        <b class="lb2"> Now At </b>
        <span class="WebRupee">Rs. </span>
          4,700
       </label>
        </span>
           <span class="offer_block">
          <a class="mtb-more" href="/Products/Buy-Online-Electronics-Cameras-Digital-Cameras/Nikon/Nikon-Coolpix-L27-Point--Shoot/pid-2849731.aspx" title="Click for more details"></div>
```

I am unable to see  "div class="bucket"" tag, after parsing.

how i can handle this?

Comment: The snippet of the page you've provided is not complete - most of the divs are not closed - can you give us an example URL of the site you're scraping? Jsoup is pretty good at handling broken HTML but it won't be able to deal with half a page like you've provided here! :-)

Comment: Thank you, 

http://www.jabraat.com/categories/Buy-Digital-Cameras-Online/cid-CU00084377.aspx
This is the url i am scraping.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us your code please?

Btw. if you want to parse a website, it's better to use `connect()` instead of `parse()`.

Here's an example how to get `<div class="controlcontent_r">...</div>` tags:

```
final String url = "http://www.jabraat.com/categories/Buy-Digital-Cameras-Online/cid-CU00084377.aspx";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

for( Element element : doc.select("div.controlcontent_r") )
{
    System.out.println(element);
    System.out.println();
}
```

This code prints three elements (separated by a blank line):

```
<div class="controlcontent_r">
 <div class="mtc-menu">
  <ul class="mtc-cat">
   <li class="mtc-block"><a class="mtc-a mtc-selected" title="Go To Digital Cameras" href="http://www.jabraat.com/categories/Buy-Digital-Cameras-Online/cid-CU00084377.aspx">Digital Cameras</a></li>
   <li class="mtc-block"><a class="mtc-a" title="Go To Camcoders" href="http://www.jabraat.com/categories/Buy-Camcorders-Online/cid-CU00084380.aspx">Camcoders</a></li>
   <li class="mtc-block1"><a class="mtc-a" title="Go To Camera Accessories" href="http://www.jabraat.com/categories/Buy-Camera-Accessories-Online/cid-CU00084381.aspx">Camera Accessories</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="controlcontent_r">
 <div class="mtc-menu">
  <ul class="mtc-cat">
   <li class="mtc-block"><a class="mtc-a" title="Go To Camera" href="http://www.jabraat.com/categories/Buy-Cameras-Online/cid-CU00084376.aspx">Camera</a></li>
   <li class="mtc-block"><a class="mtc-a" title="Go To Digital Photo Frames" href="http://www.jabraat.com/categories/Buy-Digital-Photo-Frames-Online/cid-CU00084382.aspx">Digital Photo Frames</a></li>
   <li class="mtc-block1"><a class="mtc-a" title="Go To Mobiles" href="http://www.jabraat.com/categories/Buy-Mobiles-Online/cid-CU00084383.aspx">Mobiles</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="controlcontent_r"> 
 <div class="mtc-menu"> 
  <ul class="mtc-cat">
   <li class="mtc-block"><a class="mtc-a" title="Go to Watches" href="http://www.jabraat.com/categories/Buy-Watches-Online/cid-CU00084370.aspx">Watches</a></li>
   <li class="mtc-block"><a class="mtc-a" title="Go to Clothing" href="http://www.jabraat.com/categories/Buy-Online-Clothing/cid-CU00084420.aspx">Clothing</a></li>
   <li class="mtc-block"><a class="mtc-a" title="Go to Mobiles" href="http://www.jabraat.com/categories/Buy-Mobiles-Online/cid-CU00084383.aspx">Mobiles</a></li>
   <li class="mtc-block"><a class="mtc-a" title="Go to Cameras" href="http://www.jabraat.com/categories/Buy-Cameras-Online/cid-CU00084376.aspx">Cameras</a></li>
   <li class="mtc-block"><a class="mtc-a" title="Go to Home &amp; Kitchen" href="http://www.jabraat.com/categories/Buy-Home-Kitchen-Appliances-Online/cid-CU00084391.aspx">Home &amp; Kitchen</a></li>
   <li class="mtc-block"><a class="mtc-a" title="Go to Personal Care" href="http://www.jabraat.com/categories/Buy-Online-Personal-Care/cid-CU00084413.aspx">Personal Care</a></li>
   <li class="mtc-block"><a class="mtc-a" title="Go to Jewellery" href="http://www.jabraat.com/categories/Buy-Online-Jewellery/cid-CU00084429.aspx">Jewellery</a></li>
   <li class="mtc-block1"><a class="mtc-a" title="Go to Footwear" href="http://www.jabraat.com/categories/Buy-Online-Footwear/cid-CK00101771.aspx">Footwear</a></li>
  </ul> 
 </div> 
</div>
```

---

---

### Edit:

As mentioned in the comments, things get more complicated with `<div class='bucket'>` tags. While you can easily parse the `controlcontent_r` tags using jsoup, the `bucket` looks to be generated by a script.

You can do a simple test:

```
final String url = "http://www.jabraat.com/categories/Buy-Digital-Cameras-Online/cid-CU00084377.aspx";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get(); // Connect an parse the document (as above)


System.out.println(doc); // Output the document (= how jsoup "see"'s the website)
```

There's no `bucket` tag in there, what means you can't retrieve it (with jsoup) - the solution is to use another library to execute scripts.

Conveniently i've already posted a short list of of those here: [Trying to parse html hidden by javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13666453/trying-to-parse-html-hidden-by-javascript/14715242#14715242)

Comment: Thanks & sorry ollo, I am unable to find <div class='bucket'> by mistake i typed <div class="controlcontent_r">. can u send me the code snippet for <div class="bucket"> tag under <div class="controlcontent_r"> , Thanks

Comment: No problem, but unfortunately things get more complicated for this tag. I'll edit this into my answer, just a moment ...

Answer (score 0):

TO interact with Javascript use the Selenium Framework (google it). Then you can parse the element into a JSoup element. Selenium is easy. I Learned it on the fly.