# make jsoup get the full HTML content like I can see in my browser

Tags: android, web-crawler, jsoup

I am developing android app with web crawling function. I use Jsoup to parse the HTML-content in http://infoka.krl.co.id/to/boo .

I got a huge problem because HTML-content (table content at that page) that I want is created via JavaScript. Isn't there a way to make Jsoup supporting Javascript? Or at least get the full HTML-content I can see in my browser.

I already tried HtmlUnit, but this one didn't do well. It did not give me the content I would get in my browser.

someone suggest phantomjs, but I dont know how to use it in android.

please help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to display a pagesource of a website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16250536/how-to-display-a-pagesource-of-a-website)

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't there a way to make Jsoup supporting Javascript?

Unfortunately not, you have to use another library for executing the script. Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13666453/trying-to-parse-html-hidden-by-javascript) for some examples.